# Include Parent Terms when searching for Children in WordPress Taxonomy Search

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

**My question is:** How can I set up the query so that the search includes children when querying a parent and includes the parent when querying a child?

I am using the following code to successfully search for posts of a certain type which are in both Term A *and* Term B.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'profiles',
    'tax_query' => array(                           //(array) - use taxonomy parameters (available with Version 3.1).
        'relation' => 'AND',                        //(string) - Possible values are 'AND' or 'OR' and is the equivalent of ruuning a JOIN for each taxonomy
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'skills',                 //(string) - Taxonomy.
            'field' => 'id',                        //(string) - Select taxonomy term by ('id' or 'slug')
            'terms' => array( (int)$skill_id ),     //(int/string/array) - Taxonomy term(s).
            'include_children' => true,             //(bool) - Whether or not to include children for hierarchical taxonomies. Defaults to true.
            'operator' => 'IN'                      //(string) - Operator to test. Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'towns-counties',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( (int)$area_id ),
            'include_children' => true,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    // Do Stuff
```

This works perfectly when searching for child terms if the search query is a parent, but is there a known method to search the opposite way around?

Term A is a skill or trade, e.g.: Builder, Hairdresser, Web Developer.

Term B is a place, a town/city or county within the UK, e.g: Aberdeenshire, Liverpool, Livingston etc.

Term A is *not* hierarchical. Term B *is* hierarchical.

If the end user searches for a county, the search results contain all posts which live inside that county and it's children (towns/cities).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @e.owen?